# PHP: Retrieve multiple rows from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I got a MySQL database with reviews and I am trying to retrieve and display them all using this code:

```
$retrieve_reviews = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE PRODUCT_ID = $pid";
$do_retrieve_reviews = mysqli_query($connection, $retrieve_reviews);
if(mysqli_num_rows($do_retrieve_reviews) > 0) {
    while($review_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($do_retrieve_reviews)) {
        echo '<div class="review" style="width:50%;height:200px;float:left;background:blue;display:inline;">';
        echo '<h1>' . $review_row["RATING"] . ' out of 5</h1><br>';
        echo '<p>' . $review_row["REVIEW"] . '</p>';
        echo '<h4>' . $review_row["CUSTOMER"] . '</h4>';
        echo '<h5>' . $review_row["REVIEW_DATE"] . '</h5>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

However, only the last entry in the database is always being displayed. What am I missing here?
Thanks for any ideas.

EDIT:
after testing the code with these statements added into the while loop:

```
var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($do_retrieve_reviews));
var_dump($review_row);
```

I get this results:

```
int 3
array (size=6)
'REVIEW_ID' => string '10' (length=2)
'PRODUCT_ID' => string '10' (length=2)
'RATING' => string '4' (length=1)
'REVIEW' => string 'good board' (length=10)
'CUSTOMER' => string ' Jozo  Milan ' (length=13)
'REVIEW_DATE' => string '2015-04-26 00:00:00' (length=19)

int 3
array (size=6)
'REVIEW_ID' => string '11' (length=2)
'PRODUCT_ID' => string '10' (length=2)
'RATING' => string '2' (length=1)
'REVIEW' => string 'Very bad I dont know how can even sell that for so much.     Trash!' (length=63)
'CUSTOMER' => string ' Fero  Mrkva ' (length=13)
'REVIEW_DATE' => string '2015-04-26 00:00:00' (length=19)

int 3
array (size=6)
'REVIEW_ID' => string '12' (length=2)
'PRODUCT_ID' => string '10' (length=2)
'RATING' => string '4' (length=1)
'REVIEW' => string 'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' (length=57)
'CUSTOMER' => string ' pooooo  hhhhhhh ' (length=17)
'REVIEW_DATE' => string '2015-04-26 00:00:00' (length=19)
```

Which are correct results. However, only the last one is being displayed. Very confusing.

Comment: try `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: Please format your code!

Comment: :) because you are fetching for only one data, your query seen like this instead use `SELECT * FROM reviews`

Comment: @SagarPanchal that would fetch all the reviews for all products. Whereas I am trying to fetch only those for the current product. Thats why there is the WHERE condition.

Comment: maybe you simply have 1 review for the product you;re querying? add `var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($do_retrieve_reviews))` somewhere in your code and see what it outputs. Code looks fine IMHO. maybe yu got a problem with displaying the html ? add `var_dump($review_row)` inside the loop

Comment: @murison Nope I got 3 reviews for the product I am with which I am testing this code. Btw, var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($do_retrieve_reviews)) outputs "int 3" 3 times. And var_dump($review_row) outputs all three reviews nicely in arrays. However, theres still only the last one being outputed :/

Comment: put this output in the original post - as here it loses all the formating and is very un-readable. So - you don't get "only the last row", but you get "the last row multiple times" ? how can you get the vardump 6 times, as you claim to have 3 rows? edit the code to show where you put those var_dumps

Comment: MAAAAAAAAAAAN you keep editing your comments... what dou you mean by "However, theres still only the last one being outputed". only the one is visible in the web page? If so - you must have messed up your HTML. If you get all the rows vardumped correctly - at least you know you are fetching them the right way. You just fail to display.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Yeah thats exactly what I meant - that only the last one is being visible in the web page.

Comment: once, or multiple times?

Comment: Only the last review is being visible on the page and also only the last review is generated by HTML. Once.

Comment: are you checking the source of generated HTML , or just the visual output in the browser? try better formating the HTML being output (add newlines after the tags) to make it better readable in the browser's source view)

Comment: Mayby try concatenating the output in a string, and write this string after the loop ends?

Comment: Now I just deleted echoing the <div> tags and now its finally being displayed everything! Dont know why I cannot put each review into a <div> tag though. Very strange.

Comment: You must have something messed up with the CSS. Leave the div, but throw out all the "style" and "class" stuff. I guess you'll be fine from this point

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc instead` of  `mysqli_fetch_array`

What will the different functions return?

```
mysql_fetch_row
```

This function will return a row where the values will come in the order as they are defined in the SQL query, and the keys will span from 0 to one less than the number of columns selected.

```
mysql_fetch_assoc
```

This function will return a row as an associative array where the column names will be the keys storing corresponding value.

```
mysql_fetch_array
```

This function will actually return an array with both the contents of mysql_fetch_rowand mysql_fetch_assoc merged into one. It will both have numeric and string keys which will let you access your data in whatever way you'd find easiest.

> It is recommended to use either _assoc or _row though.

this code should work.

```php
$retrieve_reviews = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE PRODUCT_ID = $pid";
$do_retrieve_reviews = mysqli_query($connection, $retrieve_reviews);
if(mysqli_num_rows($do_retrieve_reviews) > 0) {
    $review_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($do_retrieve_reviews);
    foreach($review_row as $reviews) {
        echo '<div class="review" style="width:50%;height:200px;float:left;background:blue;display:inline;">';
        echo '<h1>' . $reviews["RATING"] . ' out of 5</h1><br>';
        echo '<p>' . $reviews["REVIEW"] . '</p>';
        echo '<h4>' . $reviews["CUSTOMER"] . '</h4>';
        echo '<h5>' . $reviews["REVIEW_DATE"] . '</h5>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}  else {
    echo '<div class="review" style="width:50%;height:200px;float:left;background:blue;display:inline;">
    No Reviews available for this product yet.
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: well , i am new to stackoverflow . note taken .

Comment: With your code I am getting this error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'REVIEW' in ...\details.php on line 66 and there is one warning for each item (Rating, Review, Customer, Review_date). Any idea what it means?

Comment: Am I missing something, or is your code fetching only one row from the DB?

Comment: There are now 3 reviews in my DB for this certain product I am testing and it's only showing the last one.